# Optional class refactor

Tags: java, option-type

I wrote this ugly creature:

```
Optional<Transaction> secondSide = findSecondSide(transaction.getId());
        if(secondSide.isPresent()) {
            secondSide.get().setFlag("Y");
            save(secondSide.get());
        }
```

Is there a way I can refactor this, without using `isPresent()`and `get()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`ifPresent` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-):

```
secondSide.ifPresent(s -> { s.setFlag("Y"); save(s); });
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing were the curly brackets!

Comment: I've tried 
`secondSide.ifPresent(s -> 
    s.setBeneficiary("Y");
    save(s); 
   );`
I'm pretty new to using lambdas, so I didn't realise what I was doing wrong.

Comment: (I meant in the question).